# Can I re-attach to a detached mosh session?

Tags: mosh

When I connect using mosh I get the following error:

```
Mosh: You have 2 detached Mosh sessions on this server, with PIDs:
    - mosh [3700]
    - mosh [31091]
```

How can I resume one of these sessions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't.  Once the client is dead, you can't re-attach to the server session.

https://github.com/keithw/mosh/issues/394

> For security reasons, you can only resume a connection to a
>   mosh-server from the corresponding mosh-client. If the client is dead
>   (e.g. the user quit the client while it was off the network), the only
>   option is to kill the server with that PID (e.g. kill 12726).